# run validation on whole object level not individual properties

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js

I have a simple model `Employee` as following:

```
Employee = function(empId, fName, lName, empEmail, empPermission) {
    this.firstname = ko.observable(fName);
    this.lastname = ko.observable(lName);
    this.email = ko.observable(empEmail);
}
```

In my view user can enter many employees(by default i show 10 rows to enter 10 employees). Now i want to validate my data as(using [Knockout Validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation)):

- If user entered value for `firstname` then `lastname` && `email` should be validated, but if the user didn't enter any values for `firstname` && `lastname` && `email` then no validation need to be run.
- The same case also applied if user enter the value for only `lastname` or `email`

In simple words run validation only if one property of the object is not empty, otherwise no validation .. Any Suggestion?

Comment: Where are your validation rules?

Comment: If I extend my `Employee` object properties with validation rules then it 'll run everytime even if the user didn't enter all properties values, right?

Comment: I think so, yes. did you check `validatedObservable` https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation#getting-started ?

Comment: that's a little bit closer, but I need fire each property validation not just one validation for the whole object

Comment: I found a good solution for my problem [here](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/User-Contributed-Rules#conditional-required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you only want to fire validation when there is only one property that has no value but the rest do.

Here is how I would go about it:

```
ko.validation.configure({
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: true
});

// Utility function to count how many times something appears in an array
function countInArray(array, what) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === what) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

var Employee = function(empId, fName, lName, empEmail, empPermission) {
    var self = this;
    self.isThereSingleEmptyProp = function(){
        var props = [];
        // keep array of these 3 items we care about
        ko.utils.objectForEach(self, function(item){
            if (item === "firstname" || item ==="lastname" || item ==="email"){
                props.push(self[item]());
            }
        });
        // Returns true if only a single element does not have a value
        return countInArray(props, "") === 1;
    }
    self.firstname = ko.observable(fName || "").extend({
        required: {
            message: "Please fill all fields",
            // Checks if a property with no value is singled out
            onlyIf: self.isThereSingleEmptyProp
        }
    });
    self.lastname = ko.observable(lName || "").extend({
        required: {
            message: "Please fill all fields",
            // Checks if a property with no value is singled out
            onlyIf: self.isThereSingleEmptyProp
        }
    });
    self.email = ko.observable(empEmail || "").extend({
        required: {
            message: "Please fill all fields",
            // Checks if a property with no value is singled out
            onlyIf: self.isThereSingleEmptyProp
        }
    });
    self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);
}


ko.applyBindings(new Employee());
```

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/makeitmorehuman/rKY3Y/17/)

Comment: Thanks much it helped me alot. I found also something like this [here](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/User-Contributed-Rules#conditional-required), but i used your way